# validation for file attachment only doc and pdf in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

In the below code its is uploading all file type but i need only doc and pdf file

i want to upload only doc and pdf file help me friends may i know how to do that

Here is the code refers this any say how to validate.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Email Attachment Without Upload - Excellent Web World</title>
<style>
body{ font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;}
th{ background:#999999; text-align:right; vertical-align:top;}
input{ width:181px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="emailSend.php" method="post" name="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
       <tr>
        <th>Your Name</th>
        <td><input name="fieldFormName" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Your Email</th>
        <td><input name="fieldFormEmail" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>To Email</th>
        <td><input name="toEmail" type="text"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <td><input name="fieldSubject" type="text" id="fieldSubject"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <td><textarea name="fieldDescription" cols="20" rows="4" id="fieldDescription"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Attach Your File</th>
      <td><input name="attachment" type="file"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

emailSend.php

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$to = $_POST['toEmail'];
$fromEmail = $_POST['fieldFormEmail']; 
$fromName = $_POST['fieldFormName']; 
$subject = $_POST['fieldSubject']; 
$message = $_POST['fieldDescription'];

/* GET File Variables */ 
$tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
$fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']==doc/pdf; 
$fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

/* Start of headers */ 
$headers = "From: $fromName"; 

if (file($tmpName)) { 
  /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */
  $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
  $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
  fclose($file); 

  /* a boundary string */
 $randomVal = md5(time()); 
 $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

  /* Header for File Attachment */
 // $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
 // $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
 // $headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

  /* Multipart Boundary above message */
  $message = 



  $message . "\n\n"; 

  /* Encoding file data */
  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

  /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
  $message .=  

  " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 

  $data . "\n\n"  
  ; 
} 

$flgchk = mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message","$headers"); 

if($flgchk){
  echo "A email has been sent to: $to";
 }
else{
  echo "Error in Email sending";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check as below

```
$allowedExts = array(
  "pdf", 
  "doc", 
  "docx"
); 

$allowedMimeTypes = array( 
  'application/msword',
  'application/pdf'
);

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));


if ( ! ( in_array($extension, $allowedExts ) ) ) {
  die('Please provide another file type .');
}

if ( in_array( $_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedMimeTypes ) ) 
{      
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
}
else
{
die('Please provide another file type .');
}
```

Comment: Any reason you chose `end(explode`( as opposed to `pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`?

Comment: I'm fully aware of what it does, what I'm asking is, was there a specific reason that you choose to use non filesystem functions in order to achieve this? Meaning, is there some arbitrary gains I'm unaware of? Always looking to build on my existing knowledge.

Comment: there can be multiple '.' in a file name so it will take only the last part

Answer (score 0):

First check the MIME type of the file that was uploaded and then do a check if the allowed type is there or not.

How toCheck the MIME type..

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
echo $mimetype;
```

Your `$allowedrules array`,Also use this code to check  for  `doc and pdf` in php.

```
$allowedrules = array( 
  'application/msword',
  'text/pdf',
);
```

Update:

Otherwise use this condition,It restricts only .doc & .pdf files.

```
<?php

    $allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc", "docx");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
         echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "Success";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know you only want a php answer but you could save server ressources to do this with jQuery. Like this:

```
$("input:file").change(function () {
     if ($(this).val() !== "") {
          var ul_file = $(this).val();
          var extension = ul_file.substr((ul_file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
          var accepted_file_endings = ["doc", "docx", "doc"];
          extension = extension.toLowerCase();
          if ($.inArray(extension, accepted_file_endings) !== -1) {
          //start upload
          ...
          }
     }
});
```